# MemberMouse Subscriptions Days Counter

Tags: wordpress, membership

I am working on a MemberMouse subscription Wordpress website. On user Dashboard page, I need to display the Status of User Subscription plan. For Example, if plan is of 90 days, I want to display: Days In: 34 | Days Left: 54

```
echo do_shortcode("[MM_Form type='myaccount']");
$date = do_shortcode("[MM_Form_Data name='registrationDate']");
echo do_shortcode("[/MM_Form]");
```

I tried above code to get registration date, but getting error.
FYI I am doing this in a template file.

Any solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Akif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using following shortcodes:

Days In: `[MM_Member_Data name='daysAsMember']`